# Converting boolean values to text in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I was wondering what is the best way to convert a boolean value retrieved from the database to text for use in a display-field or textbox (e.g. true or false to Male or Female). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the conversion in the view - IMHO this is not against MVC.
If you want to go hardcore with your design create a new class/struct "Gender" with static creation methods/properties "Male", "Female", overload the ToString accordingly and cast-operators to bool or a constructor with bool and a ToBool function.

Answer (score 0):

@((bool)item.BooleanColumn ? "Yes" : "No")